# Chevy Cruze with a funny sound when applying the brakes. The drums, pads and shoes among other things were replaced

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, noise

When applying the brakes on my 2013 Chevrolet Cruze, a loud funny noise happens. I'm frustrated that this is my first vehicle I have purchased on my own and all I can think is it's just my luck.

I will be taking my car in for a third time this month to the dealership in a couple of days and would like to ask the right questions or suggest something when I go in. I can't be the only one with an issue like this. Can anybody help me? I would greatly appreciate it. Any ideas or suggestions?

And my previous visits they have replaced my drums, pads and shoes. On my last visit I thought it was fixed or resolved but the noise came back a couple of days later. Almost seems worse.

Comment: Please describe the noise. 'Funny' doesn't tell us anything. If it is a squeal or a grind then we have a range of questions which cover this off so use the search function first.

Comment: Here are some suggestions on describing the sound: is it a squeak or a scrape?  How loud is loud?  Louder than the engine?  Louder than the radio?  Can you hear it with the windows up or down?  Does the sound only happen with the brakes?  How quickly does it go away?  Some information like that would help us provide more useful suggestions.

Comment: Have the same issue with my 2013 Cruze, braking causes brakes to squeal also In shop for third time. First time resurfaced rotors in front and cleaned and adjusted rear brakes. Picked up car and drove it and same thing happened again so back to shop they said if condensation was on rotors it would make noise and said a car with age on it (43000 miles on it now) the brakes would make the noise. I drove in all types of weather and still doing it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't properly break in your pads/shoes then the squeal will likely just come right back. You have to avoid hard or excessive braking for at least 50km after doing a change like that.

However, your calipers could be bad and cause your pads to not seat properly or warp the rotors causing noise.